# Is there a cursive font in the Android stock browsers?

Tags: android, css, fonts

As a part of offering example themes for a website, to show it is possible with LESS, I am using a cursive font-family. For example:

```
@base-font-family-fonts: 'Lucida Handwriting', 'Comic Sans', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Chalkboard', cursive;
```

I've tried naming many different cursive font, but not even the fallback "cursive" works on the stock Android browser (Samsung Galaxy S4).

Do I really need to download a font to the browser on Android? Is there not a single one built in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle with android safe font families and unfortunately you will see there is not a stock cursive font.

If I were you, I would use Google Fonts to make your cursive text look consistent across all browsers and operating systems though.

http://jsfiddle.net/9z3tD/

```
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: normal">Regular</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic">Italic</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold">Bold</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Bold-italic</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-light; font-style: normal">Light</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-light; font-style: italic">Light-italic</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-thin; font-style: normal">Thin</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-thin; font-style: italic">Thin-italic</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-condensed; font-style: normal">Condensed regular</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-condensed; font-style: italic">Condensed italic</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif-condensed; font-weight: bold">Condensed bold</div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Condensed bold-italic</div>
```

Comment: You know what? I'm gonna accept that as an answer in the absence of any others. You've provided a decent solution.